# How do you get the sum of the last 14 filled values in a column?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

As the title say, how do you get the sum of the last 14 filled values in a column?

I can have a row of e.g. 100 posts, but only want the sum of the last 14 rows. How do you get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it. I don't know if there is an easier solution, but at least it works :)

The code looks like this:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(COUNTA(B2:B1048576)-8;2)&":"&ADDRESS(COUNTA(B2:B1048576)+1;2)))
```

- The -8 is the number of rows you want to go back
- 2 is the column number
- +1 is the end row offset

Comment: Are you sure you need the MAX functions? I think the COUNTA does it for you and you are taking the max of a single value. Also, the question talks about 14 values and the answer uses 8 (and doesn't the -8 and +1 give you 10 rows?).

Comment: @fixer1234 You are probably right. I will test it.

Comment: @fixer1234 You are right. No Max is needed. I will update my answer :)

Comment: One more fix.  COUNTA gives you the count, but then you need to offset things relative to the range where the values are.  Since the first value is in row 2, the +1 for the end row offset is right (but the explanation refers to -1).  For the start row, you need -8+2 if you want to keep the logic visible, or -6.